# The error in Android Studio is related to gradle

Tags: android-studio

An error occurs when synchronizing the project. More details on the screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKQrB.png)

My settings.gradle file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRS5D.png)

My build.gradle file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtTFG.png)

My gradle-wrapper.properties file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diuW8.png)
There is a lower version in distributionUrl because I changed it. But it didn't help.

At first it was a basic gradle file, after which, according to information from the Internet, I changed it. All changes are already shown in the screenshots. The gradle base file doesn't work either.

I was reinstalling the studio. Created new projects. Deleted local studio files. None of this helped.